# How to know free disk size witout df command?

Tags: linux, embedded, disk-usage

Is it possible to check free disk size in Linux **without using command lines such as `df`**?

Since my host machine is embedded Linux, there are no direct command lines that show free disk size.

Comment: Don't cross post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009192/how-to-know-free-disk-size-without-df-command

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "direct command lines". Do you mean you have no shell and you need to access that data programmatically?

Comment: I just have simple commands such as ls, cd, cat, etc. No busybox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The information that `df` produces comes from the `statvfs()` system call. If your embedded system does not have the `df` command installed, perhaps it has one of the common scripting languages, using which you can write a one-liner to access the same system call?

```
python -c 'import os; print os.statvfs("/")'
```

If it doesn't have anything like that installed already then your best bet is robably to write a small C program that calls `statvfs()` and install that.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I wrote a simple C program using starvfs(), which works very similar to df.